# Image not uploading from outside the directory

Tags: php

Here I am using php to upload image in database.Also i want to achieve compression before saving it in its respective folder.

**Problem:**

I face here is that it works on images already present in the directory not on the any random image present outside the directory(images/)

Any Help in correcting the code is appreciated.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  if (isset ($_FILES['new_image']))
   {     
    $imagename = $_FILES['new_image']['name'];
    $source = $_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'];
    $target = "images/".$imagename;
    $imagepath = $imagename;
    $source_url=$source;
  
   function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {
        $info = getimagesize($source_url);
        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
        {
         $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
         imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
        }elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif'){ 
          $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
          imagegif($image, $destination_url, $quality);
     }
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
    {$image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
      imagepng($image, $destination_url, $quality);
    }
 

    return $destination_url;
}
 
$source_photo = "images/" . $imagepath;
$dest_photo = ""images/sml_" . $imagepath;
 
$d = compress_image($source_photo, $dest_photo,70);
echo '
<div style="float:left;margin-right:10px">
    <img src="'.$source_photo.'" alt="" />
    <br />'.filesize($source_photo).' Bytes
</div>
 
<div style="float:left;">
    <img src="'.$dest_photo.'" alt="" />
    <br />'.filesize($dest_photo).' Bytes
</div>
';
 }}
?>
```

Comment: string concatenation problem here `$dest_photo = ""images/sml_" . $imagepath;` instead of `$dest_photo = "images/sml_" . $imagepath;`

Comment: Tried this it didnt work @JulioSoares

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be okay. It's saying folder is not exists,

Comment: Warning: getimagesize(images/Black-Desktop-Wallpaper.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\2\w1.php on line 24                                                          This is the error it gives for any andom image @Jitendra Kumar. Balla

Answer (score 0):

Here function
move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
can be used it will transfer the file to respective folder and problem is solved.